# Does Empty Azure App Service Plan Cost Anything?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-plans

I have deleted all web-apps inside the plan, can I retain the app service plan for later use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can. Just make sure it is scaled back to the Free tier so that it does not cost you. You can do this via script or on the Scale-Up menu option from the App Service plan in the portal.

You can find the App Service plan pricing [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/pricing/details/app-service/).